# Subsequence in a sequence of numbers

Tags: python

I'm looking for an elegant solution for this problem in python(without using inbuilt functions).

```
Example: 4, 3, 8, 2, 5, 9, 110
Result: 4, 8, 5,9, 110
Example: 6, 6, 6
Result: 6
Example: 9, 8, 7
Result: 9
Example: 1, 2, 3
Result: 1,2,3
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the result to list all the numbers that are greater than or equal to the first element in the given list? That's what your examples seem to indicate (although that isn't what happens in the first one)

Comment: Python comes with batteries include. Why not use them?

Comment: What would be the output of `5 10 7`? Would it be `5 10 7`, or `5 10` ?

Comment: I take it the `5` in your first result is an error?

Comment: What's your current code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def foo(seq):
  if seq == None or seq == []:
    return []
  outp = [seq[0]]
  for a in seq:
    if a > outp[-1]:
      outp.append(a)
  return outp
```

Comment: The OP said no loops!

Comment: oh, sorry, didn't see that

Comment: Thanks, but i for got to mention that it should be done without using any inbuilt functions (only for, while and if loops are allowed).

Comment: There's no way this is happening without a loop. Maybe replacing it with some fancy in-built function that simply does the loop under the hood, but there definitely needs to be a loop (i.e., the list has to be traversed completely atleast once)

Comment: what in-built function did i use except for append?

Comment: @Pramod If you want to avoid using `append` (which is the only function I've used here), you can create a new array with the length of the old and fill it with `None`s.

Comment: hi, to be specific i want the result to list all the numbers that are greater than its previous element in the given list? Eg in [1,2,3] 2>3,  3>2, so the output should be [1,2,3] and in [9,8,7] output should be 9 since 8<9 and also 7<8 but if the seq is [9,8,10], then the output is [9,10].

Comment: If you want to be nitpicky about it, you could say that `.append()` is a method, not a function. So this should be legal.

Comment: @Pramod I've done it without loops, and its a recursive function. No imports either.

Comment: @Pramod I have understood that and tested your examples against my solution. They all returned what I (and you) expected them to return.

Comment: @Gilad Thank you very much. Your code works very well. Also it needs to satisfy two more conditions. 1. It should also work for negative numbers eg: ([-1,-2,-3]) as well, 2. If the input is empty array ([]), then in should give [] as output. I tried to modify your code, but failed after many attempts.

Comment: @Pramod The code works fine for negative numbers. I'll change it to support empty lists. If this answer satisfies you, please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Gilad I tried this with the code: foo([-1,-2,-3,-4]) i get [-1], but when i try foo([-4,-3,-2,-1]) i get [-4].. Also i was able to modify it for the empty lists. Just need to get the negative lists to work.

Comment: By your specifications, you're supposed to get `[-1]` in the first case. The console output on my machine for the second case:
`>>> foo([-4,-3,-2,-1]) # => [-4, -3, -2, -1]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive solution:

```
def greater_adder(l):

    def list_iter(stack, li):

        if not li:
            return stack

        if stack[-1] < li[0]:
            stack.append(li[0])
            return list_iter(stack, li[1:])
        else:
            return list_iter(stack, li[1:])

    return list_iter([l[0]], l[1:])
```

Console session:

```
>>> from higher_up import greater_adder
>>> nums = [4, 3, 8, 2, 5, 9, 110]
>>> greater_adder(nums)
Out[5]: [4, 8, 9, 110]
>>> nums = [6, 6, 6]
>>> greater_adder(nums)
Out[7]: [6]
>>> nums = [9, 8, 7]
>>> greater_adder(nums)
Out[9]: [9]
>>> nums = [1,2,3]
>>> greater_adder(nums)
Out[11]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know the length of the string you want to manipulate beforehand, you can not do much with that string. 
And even if you do know the string's length, the solution is going to be anything but elegant.

Answer (score 0):

This method uses list comprehensions and enumerate(). You have to use some kind of loops or build-ins anyway, so I would go with a solution like this.

```
>>a = [1, 2, 1, 5, 4, 6]
>>[x for i, x in enumerate(a) if i == 0 or a[i] > a[i-1]]
[1, 2, 5, 6]
```